# SlideToggle div does not work

Tags: jquery

I've this code :

```js
$('.close-button').click(function() {
 $(this).closest('#hidden').slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="bloc">
  <h2>Click on that link to display the content <a href="#" class="close-button">Click here</a></h2>
  <div id="hidden">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus augue ante, fringilla ac sodales et, vehicula pellentesque ante. Integer id mattis erat, nec tincidunt nisi. </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="bloc">
  <h2>Click on that link to display the content <a href="#" "close-button">Click here</a></h2>
  <div id="hidden">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus augue ante, fringilla ac sodales et, vehicula pellentesque ante. Integer id mattis erat, nec tincidunt nisi. </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

When you click on the link, the div `#hidden` is displayed.

I try to do this in Jquery but it does not work.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use duplicate `id`, instead use a `class`.

`.closest` only looks up through the parents, and not of the siblings to those parents.

```js
$('.close-button').click(function() {
 $(this).parent().next().slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.hidden{
    display:none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="bloc">
  <h2>Click on that link to display the content <a href="#" class="close-button">Click here</a></h2>
  <div class="hidden">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus augue ante, fringilla ac sodales et, vehicula pellentesque ante. Integer id mattis erat, nec tincidunt nisi. </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="bloc">
  <h2>Click on that link to display the content <a href="#" class="close-button">Click here</a></h2>
  <div class="hidden">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus augue ante, fringilla ac sodales et, vehicula pellentesque ante. Integer id mattis erat, nec tincidunt nisi. </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First grab the [parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent) element and then get the [next](http://api.jquery.com/next) element to it:

```
$('.close-button').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next().slideToggle();
});
```

To note: the [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest) method gets the element's closest parent element.